# Isn't linear time O(n)?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, big-o-notation, quicksort

In the question in [this video about quicksort](https://youtu.be/kqO46FOUTbI?t=569) luckily picking the median in each recursive call. Tim Roughgarden, the presenter, says at 11:22

> Partition needs really linear time, not just $O(n)$ time.

What does he mean here? I thought linear time is $O(n)$. Does he mean $\Theta(n)$ or something else? I see how partition in quicksort here would be $\Theta(n)$ but I don't get the part that says "*not just $O(n)$ time*".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually we call statement $A$ stronger than $B$ when $A$ implies $B$: $A \Rightarrow B$ ([weaker-stronger](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884417/what-does-mean-weaker-and-stronger-terms-in-logic)). In other words, $B$ is weaker than $A$.

When the presenter is speaking about linear time for partition, this is a stronger statement than $O(n)$ time. All linear functions are in $O(n)$, but it also contains non-linear functions.

For example: $\sin n, \frac{1}{n}, \sqrt{n} $ are all in $O(n)$, but they are not linear. As was written in a comment, $O(n)$ is the set of functions **bounded by linear functions**, but not the set of *only* linear functions.

To be linear gives more information than to be in $O(n)$, to be in $\Omega(n)$, even to be in $\Theta(n)$.

Comment: Thanks @Acccumulation. Of course it is "than". . (I wrote this thanks already once and it was deleted by somebody).

Answer (score 3):

> The partition needs really linear time

Here, the presenter meant that partition takes $\Omega(n)$ time.

> not just $O(n)$ time

Here, the presenter meant that this is a loose or weak statement. A stronger statement would be that partition takes $\Omega(n)$ and $O(n)$ time, which is equivalent to $\Theta(n)$, as you are saying.

Comment: He didn't say "at least linear time", so I'd argue the first part should be Θ(n) rather than Ω(n).

Comment: @BernhardBarker Since it is an informal statement, it is hard to say what it precisely means. I felt that "needs" means "requires at least"

Comment: @BernhardBarker: Given that we already know it's possible in O(n), saying something that means "at least linear" amounts to saying that a good algorithm will run in Θ(n).  I find the whole thing a strange and confusing way of expressing the point, but maybe it made more sense in context.  And if spoken in a video, maybe would be something they would have changed if doing over again but didn't want to re-record a segment.